# Private Key changes between exports from a .PFX (PKCS#12) File

Tags: security, openssl, x509certificate, public-key-encryption, network-security

I am Exporting only the private key(s) from a .pfx file to a .pem (.key) file:

I am using the command as below.....I executed the command twice to generate the private key twice (It asks me for a import password and a PEM pass phrase each time) in two different physical files

> openssl pkcs12 -nocerts -in DigitalCertificateExport.pfx -out
>   OnlyKey_SameParaPhrase_1.key openssl pkcs12 -nocerts -in
>   DigitalCertificateExport.pfx -out OnlyKey_SameParaPhrase_2.key

However, the resulting key file has different private key each time. Should it not be the same always? I was expecting it to be the same each time.

Worth mentioning that I provide exactly the same pass phrase each time.

Comment: Is the private key different or the file? Even when you use the same passphrase the file will be different because the encryption is based on a random key.

Comment: Thanks @StephanB . . . The key as in the generated .key file is different each time. But if the encryption is based on random key then this explains the behaviour. Thanks for your commment. If you could post this as an answer then I will accept it.

Comment: It is not a random key but a random salt, at least in the key I converted. See the answer and linked doc.

Comment: If you use `-nodes` to output _unencrypted_ privatekey it will be the same each time. But in many cases this makes it easy for an adversary to misuse your key to steal and/or falsify all your important data, which some people might consider undesirable. (Yes the option remains `-nodes` even though the encryption algorithm used nowadays is usually 3DES/TDEA or even something quite different like AES or ARIA.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this OpenSSL doc](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/pem.html#PEM_ENCRYPTION_FORMAT), at least some encryption methods for .pem files use a random salt. When using your command to convert a .pfx file I get a file with the following line:

`-DEK-Info: DES-EDE3-CBC,6AC8DB439F2BDE03`

This cointains a random salt used for encryption and / or validation.

Comment: Even for PKCS8 encryption as opposed to legacy-PEM encryption there is random salt, though no longer in the PEM header, and in OpenSSL 1.0.0 up (released 2010 but many systems took a while to adopt) commandline `pkcs12 (import)` writes PKCS8 not legacy-PEM